# Manually setting focus keyword on website

Tags: wordpress, seo

Can anyone please tell me how to set a focus keyword myself without `Yoast` `SEO`?

Answer (score 2):

Find your `header.php` file of the active theme. then add the following html line, inside `< head>......< /head>` before the `< link>` tags.

```
<meta name="Keywords" content="focus keyword 1,focus keyword 2,focus keyword 3,focus keyword 4">
```

add you focus keywords and comma separate them.

**Important Note:** Its bad practice for WordPress sites to add keywords directly with out a plugin. Because, using a plugin allows you to have different keywords for different pages as well as posts.
But doing it manually, all of your sites pages will have the same focus keywords,because you have to add a meta tag to the themes `header.php`(one `header.php` file used by  all pages). which may lead to bad ranking.

Answer (score 0):

The focus keyword has no effect on SEO. It is used by Yoast simply to provide a metric on which to judge the content of a page. Adding a focus keyword yourself does nothing.

See here http://www.matteoduo.com/focus-keyword-wordpress-seo/

> The focus keyword is nothing else than a writing tool you can exploit to improve your writing while creating a page or a blog post.